# Transpositions To Disjoint Cycles

Tags: group-theory

If I have the following permeation $$(1,5)(2,5)(3,5)(4,5)$$ how do I write it as disjoint cycles?

I start with the rightmost cycle with and for example $4\to 5\to 3 \to 5 \to 2 \to 1$

Comment: You computed the cycle incorrectly. $5$ cannot map to both $3$ and $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Start off and check what happens to 1 if we apply each of the cycles from the right:
$$1 \to 5$$
So we start with:
$$(1,5,$$
Now see what happens to the 5:
$$5 \to 4 $$
So we now have:
$$(1,5,4,$$
Now see what happens to the 4 (bit more interesting):
$$4 \to 5 \to 3$$
So now we have:
$$(1,5,4,3,$$
Finally we see what happens to the 3:
$$3 \to 5 \to 2$$
So our full cycle is:
$$(1,5,4,3,2)$$

Comment: Are you sure about this — I composed the cycles from right to left when calculating?

Comment: Why in $4$ you move form one cycle to another and in $5$ for example you did not

Comment: @newhere For each number you check what happens to it in $every$ bracket (from the right), for 5 it goes to 4 in the first, and then that’s it because 4 doesn’t go to anything else. For 4, it goes to 5 in the first bracket, which then goes to three in the second bracket, which doesn’t go to anything else in any after.

Comment: but $5$ appear in each bracket

Comment: @newhere but you only apply each bracket once before moving to the right

Answer (score 1):

skill in multiplying permutations comes with practice. however to help clarify what actually occurs it may be easier, to begin with, if you think of each element of the permutation group $S_5$ as a mapping of a sequence of five distinct items to another sequence of the same items, then $(34)$, for example, means: exchange the item in place $3$ with the item in place $4$.
$$
\begin{align}
(15)(25)(35)(45) (\text{ABCDE}) &=  (15)(25)(35) (\text{ABCED}) \\
                       &=  (15)(25) (\text{ABDEC}) \\
                       &=   (15) (\text{ACDEB}) \\
                       &=   \text{BCDEA} \\
                       &=   (15432) (\text{ABCDE}) 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I got the till the BCDEA part but how you got to $(15432)(ABCDE)$?

Comment: the $A$ (initially in position 1) goes to position 5.
the $E$ (initially in position 5) goes to position 4.
the $D$ (initially in position 4) goes to position 3.
the $C$ (initially in position 3) goes to position 2.
the $B$ (initially in position 2) goes to position 1.